# Fiddler - add latency on single response without modifying response

Tags: fiddler

In Fiddler how can I slow down the response of a **specific** request *only*, while passing through the response from the server?

I'm aware I can simulate a slow speed for all requests - that's not what I want.

Using the **AutoResponder** with a specific rule forces me to choose what to respond with.

[image]

How can I use the "Latency" feature without modifying the response? Is this possible in Fiddler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understood your question that you want to delay either request or response time for a specific request.

You could do it with the FiddlerScript module by updating the oSession object.

*onBeforeRequest*

```
// Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.
oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "300";
```

*onBeforeResponse*

```
// Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.
oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150";
```

You would also need to filter the correct request in the selected method.

*Filtering*

```
// Sample Rule: Break requests for URLs containing "/path/"
if (oSession.uriContains("/path/")) {
}

if (oSession.hostname == "some.hostname") {
}

if (oSession.url == "some.url") {
}
```

Additional info can be found [here](https://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp)

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you show how to do the URL filtering here, so the answer addresses the question completely?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the latency feature, you can enter `*delay:5000` as the **then respond with...** command, instead of a file path.

I noticed that the rules are ignored with a blank response, so you can use the latency with a command/path of `*action`, which isn't a real action, but causes the rule to execute and the latency to take effect, in case you really want to use the Latency column.